# Using PHPMailer send attachment file in PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I currently using PHPMailer to sending mail with attachment file in localhost and also in my server.

The problem I have is the attachment file does not receive in email when execute in server. But in other side, the attachment file receive perfectly when I execute on localhost.

Here is my simple code:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'william@msmedia.com.sg';
$email->FromName  = 'John';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = 'test';
$email->AddAddress( 'william@msmedia.com.sg' );
$file_to_attach = $_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"];
$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , $_FILES["cv"]["name"]);            
return $email->Send();
```

Can anyone able to correct my mistake..?

Comment: How big is the file? Maybe the server has a message size limit.

Comment: Could be permissions on the file too - make sure it's readable from your script

Comment: @Barmar Even I tried to attach an image also cannot receive that.

Comment: @Synchro What it mean on "permissions on the file" ..?

Comment: The user that your script runs as (probably the web server user) needs to have read permissions on the file. try sending a file that is already on the server rather than one you are uploading. Then make sure you are handling the upload correctly - [do what the docs say](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).